# Please help me to identify this piece

Tags: classical-music, piano

Could you please help me identify this classical piece from this small passage?

https://voca.ro/1nl7M9LMRqV0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impromptu Op 90 No 2 in E-Flat Major by Franz Schubert.

[https://youtu.be/QDVJkxGz_Tc?t=686](https://youtu.be/QDVJkxGz_Tc?t=689)

There's two sets of four impromptus (Op 90 and 142), all highly recommended.

Comment: do you think the following piece is also a work of Franz Schubert? Sounds very similar but don't know if it's from Op 90 No 2   https://vocaroo.com/15C9eodP8i8V

Comment: I don't think it is.... maybe from one of the "Six moments musicaux"?

Comment: I listened to the six moments just then and didn't recognize it. Not sure where it could be from. Always thanks for your help bro :)

Comment: its Solfeggietto by C.P.E. Bach